# Google Access Token Empty

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-api

I tried in codeigniter.

Below I put this code in a construct

```
$this->google = new Google_Client();
$this->google->setClientId(GOOGLEID);
$this->google->setClientSecret(GOOGLESECRET);
$this->google->setDeveloperKey(GOOGLEAPIKEY);

$objOAuthService = new Google_Service_Oauth2($this->google);
```

then in a method1 I put the below

```
$this->google->setRedirectUri(site_url('auth/google-login?'));
$this->google->addScope("email");
$this->google->addScope("profile");
$data['content_data']['google_login_url'] = $this->google->createAuthUrl();
$this->load->view("test", $data);
```

then in method2 I put the below

```
if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
    $this->google->authenticate($_GET['code']);
    $token = $this->google->getRefreshToken();
    echo $token;
}
```

You can see that I tried to print the $token but it's empty.
My Question is WHY is it empty?

EDIT:

```
echo $this->google->getAccessToken();
```

Even the getAccessToken returns empty.

Comment: use refresh_token instead of getRefreshToken

Comment: What is the parameter to be passed for the refresh_token?

Comment: are you loading some kind of google library first? have you tested that its being loaded successfully?

Comment: I did call $objOAuthService = new Google_Service_Oauth2($this->google); in the construct before method calling and it didnn't return any error

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code which I'm using in Laravel and Codeigniter.

```
// Initial config
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName(APP_NAME);
$client->setClientId(CLIENT_ID);
$client->setClientSecret(CLIENT_SECRET);
$client->setRedirectUri(REDIRECT_URI);
$client->setScopes(array(SCOPE_A));

// To retrieve refresh token forcefully
// This will ask for permission everytime.
$client->setApprovalPrompt('force');
$client->setAccessType('offline');


// Return url data part
if (isset($_GET['code'])) {

    // Log the user in
    $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);

    // Get acess token and refresh token
    $getAccesToken = $client->getAccessToken();
    $getRefreshToken = $client->getRefreshToken();

} 
else 
{
    // Return to login
    $googleAuthUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
    // Redirect user to authentication URI

}
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed it.

My Solution is that in the construct I have

```
$this->google = new Google_Client();
$this->google->setClientId(GOOGLEID);
$this->google->setClientSecret(GOOGLESECRET);
$this->google->setDeveloperKey(GOOGLEAPIKEY);

$this->google->setRedirectUri(site_url('auth/google-login?'));
$this->google->addScope("email");
$this->google->addScope("profile");
```

in method1 I only have this

```
$data['content_data']['google_login_url'] = $this->google->createAuthUrl();
$this->load->view("test", $data);
```

and in method2 I have this

```
if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
    $this->google->authenticate($_GET['code']);
    $token = $this->google->getAccessToken();
    var_dump($token);
}
```

and here the $token already now has value